# Debian - more network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ip

I have dedicated server from OVH with additional ipv4, I have added the IP to the system interface configuration (debian), I can access the machine from both IPs now, but for some reason the first response I receive from the additional ip set as eth0:0 is way slower then from the first original ip set as eth0.

Could this be caused by wrong configuration in the system or it is problem caused on OVH side ?

Comment: How are you measuring that it is slower?  Have you tried a simple iperf test against the new IP?  Adding a **secondary address** via the `eth0:0` doesn't add additional interfaces or anything.  It really shouldn't make any difference.  One other thing you might check is the traceroute for the two IPs.  Do they follow different network paths or something?

Comment: I have 2 game servers there, each one on one of the IPs, the first server that is on the default IP I can see in my server list instantly but the second one it takes up to 6 seconds to show me that the server is online. But when I connect I dont have any lags or ping issues, just the first connection is slow.